# Excel 2010 - Date Format ('%y%m') PLUS 1 month (Jan+1=Feb) and use an IF Query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Info:**  Excel 2010 (no macros)
**Data Origns:** MySQL Query / phpMyAdmin **Server:**  Apache
**Code is run via:** Server SQL Query (copy & paste in the phpMyAdmin) or in MySQL Workbench or using a custom shopping cart manager.
**Exports to:** Excel (.csv then to .xlsx for sales reports)
**Notes:** The workbook uses my Query as well as other data

My question is in 2 parts:
1)  The basic formula for adding X months to an existing Year/Month
2)  Extending that formula to be included in an "IF" Formula
    If possible, not just the EXCEL but also the SQL formula

My columns are all formatted in my from my MySQL Query as below:
`DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%b') As PayMonth,`

I am wanting to achieve the same in Excel with the results, but with data not pulled from the query, I insert them from other data sources.

**NOTE** I don't want to have column 'D' showing, this should be in the formula.  The idea is that I can manually place the formula if I don't need the "IF" request below.
e.g.  B2+(formula D2) = E2  -->  2013-12-Dec Payable 2014-01-Jan

```
  |     A     |      B      |      C      |     D   |      E     |
1 |salesdate  | salesmonth  | Distributor | +Months | Due
2 |2013/12/28 | 2013-12-Dec | 1           | 1       | 2014-01-Jan
3 |2013/11/16 | 2013-11-Nov | 2           | 2       | 2014-01-Jan
4 |2013/10/15 | 2013-10-Oct | 3           | 3       | 2014-01-Jan
```

My request then extends to using it in an IF equation:
`DUE(Col E) = Date (ColB)+ (IF (Distributor=3 +(3 months) OR (Distributor=2 +(2 months) OR etc etc`
I can have up to 5 distributors, so my OR may be long.
Again, I don't want to even have a 'D' column, I can include it in a data sheet to be called from if needs be, but I don't want it in the sheet i'm working in.

I've tried a number of ways of doing this but I'm unfamiliar with how the IF & Date functions work in Excel.
e.g.  `=DATE(YEAR(F7),MONTH(F7)+5+1,0)` 
it works when the date is 28/12/2013 , not when I have it in 2013-12-Dec

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE** Using: `=DATE(YEAR(F2), MONTH(F2)+1+1,)` AND Format Cells (Custom) `yyyy-mm-mmm` I have the correct result if I am using Col A.
It does not work with Col B it results in a `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: Based on your update, it looks like ColB may not be formatted as date - can you check that?

Comment: @Chris I have told it to format as a custom date, but doesn't seem to hold it. I can use ColA as the basis to calculate from in excel.  So then all I need is the "IF" capability to define month by what distributor ID is in C.  Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add n months to a date in A2 using excel you can use either

`=DATE(A2,MONTH(A2)+n,DAY(A2))`

or

`=EDATE(A2,n)`

A2 needs to be a valid date

You will get slightly different results if that day doesn't exist in the target month, e.g. if A2 = 31-Jan-2014 and n = 1 the first formula gives you 3-Mar-2014 and the latter will give you 28-Feb-2014

`EDATE` never goes beyond the end of the target month

Comment: thank you the EDATE worked easily. It still doesn't like ColB, but I think that's just the way the SQL exported it as. I can copy A to B and format B as yyyy-mm-mmm then run it EDATE.
Will EDATE work in the "IF" formula I need?  I have over 5 Distributors & I do a sort by date so having the equivalent to `DUE(Col E) = Date (ColB)+ (IF (Distributor=3 +(3 months) OR (Distributor=2 +(2 months) OR etc etc` would be great :)

Comment: Is the distributor number actually equal to the number of months you want to add....or is that just a simplified example?

Comment: It's the simplified example.  The actual info is:  DistID (ColX). Dist 1= 1, 2=1, 3=2, 4=3.  I edit it if our contracts change or we get a new outlet onboard.  The distributor col will also change in a few months, but I can edit it as needs be.  C2/X2/Z2 etc

Comment: Yes, you can put an IF function in EDATE in place of n so that would be `EDATE(A2,If_function)` but it might be simpler if you construct a two column table with distributors in 1st col and months in 2nd and then use this version `EDATE(A2,VLOOKUP(C2,Table,2,0))`

Comment: AWESOME!  That worked, thank you.  I used the VLOOKUP option as I can create and edit tables on my data sheet as I need to.  I've also got a functions sheet which has all the functions I have used, so this is perfect.  Thanks heaps!  Have a great day.